# NameError: name 'grade' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that will number grade output when the user enters a letter grade. I am getting this error:  NameError: name 'grade' is not defined.  Can someone tell me what this error means and help me figure out how to fix it.  I am new to programming so I am realy lost.

```
letterGrade = (input("Please enter a letter grade: "))

if grade >= A:
    grade == "4.0"
elif grade < A:
      grade < "4.0"
print(grade)
```

Comment: You create a variable named `letterGrade` then compare to `grade` which you never declared. Also you are mixing up comparison (`==`) with assignment (`=`)

Comment: Ask yourself, what is grade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your if statements are checking for the variable `grade`, but your input is being assigned to `letterGrade`. You can fix this either by changing your first line to

`grade = input("Please enter a letter grade: ")`

or change every instance of `grade` to `letterGrade`.

Additionally, `grade == "4.0"` should probably be `grade = "4.0"`; `x == y` checks if x is equal to y, whereas `x = y` sets x equal to y.

Comment: No problem! You might also want to look at `grade == "4.0"` and `grade < "4.0"` - these are going to return False every time your code runs because grade is whatever the user inputs and == and < are comparisons.

Anyway, if this answered your question please mark as answered :)